# Webdriverbackedselenium cannot access selenium commands from functions

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I have a method called test, where I have defined a Webdriver object like this:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxprofile);
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "https://10.17.17.212:4343");
```

i can use selenium commands in this function, like 
selenium.click() etc.

but I cannot use them in function that I call from this function. 
e.g. i call a function called set() (private int set)
inside set

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to overcome this problem? I need to access that object from the other function

Comment: Make it static, and a class-level field, or put it into an abstract/base class and have your tests inherit from it or pass it into your tests.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by declaring WebDriver variable as static.
in my code it looks like:

```
public class BaseSeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestBase {
    static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
    }
    @Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {
        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeFirefox(){
        driver.quit();
    }
....
//blablabla}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make selenium object outside method and declare it as static so that you could use it globally.